# How to make web application as Use Application-owned Accounts in server side google drive PHP

Tags: php, mysql, google-drive-api

i wanna make web application use google drive sdk on PHP. when user login to my web using its own credential (ex username : lalala) will automatically login to user google account without user know like background login(silent mode) no redirect to google. username, email and password user save in mysql. user can upload file to google drive with my web application but not redirect to drive.google.com. how to make it? can someone give me an full example, please...

Answer (score 1):

[ClientLogin](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/AuthForInstalledApps) which implements basic authorization is deprecated across the Google products, you need to implement OAuth2 workflow for user accounts.